# what first output argument of ls -lin means

Tags: linux, ls

I have a test, where you need to find an identical file to the file `ufx`, and the answer would be the file `htt`. So the first argument is the same for those two files, and I don't know what do those numbers 100, 101, 102 mean?

You can have this result by typing in terminal `$ls –lin`

```
 100 -rw-r--r-- X usr1 group 38 2011-02-26 06:35 ufx

 101 -rw-r--r-- X usr1 group 38 2011-02-26 06:35 yaw

 101 -rw-r--r-- X usr1 group 38 2011-02-26 06:35 nuj

 100 -rw-r--r-- X usr1 group 38 2011-02-26 06:35 htt

 101 -rw-r--r-- X usr1 group 38 2011-02-26 06:35 xpa

 102 -rw-r--r-- X usr1 group 38 2011-02-26 06:35 tjp
```

Comment: You should have a look at the manpage for `ls`, especially the '-i' flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page states this under `-i`:

> ```
>    -i, --inode
>           print the index number of each file
> ```

The inode is a filesystem index to file/directory table of that file system. Read more about it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode